# Port android open GL code to iPhone

Tags: android, iphone, opengl-es

How to port android open GL code to iPhone ? There are lot of bytebuffer, floatbuffer used in the code which i am not able to convert.

Comment: Android and iOs both support OpenGL ES 2.0 so the purely OpenGL parts should be identical. For the rest, you'll need to detail what you've got, what you've tried, etc. to make this question answerable !

Answer (score 2):

bytebuffers/floatbuffers are simply byte arrays and float arrays but uses native allocation other than allocation in the JVM, which is more efficient. You can write your own class to wrap the functionalities of ByteBuffer/FloatBuffer in Objective-C.